# How to connect 2 VMware machines to ping each other

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, windows-networking

I would like to **ping** between **VM1** and **VM2**.
Using **VMware** Workstation 14.

***IDEA***

I do Windows deployment for school purposes. VM1 is server with DNS, DHCP, etc. roles. VM2 is blank, gets IP from DHCP pool, loads boot image and installs OS.

**VM1** (Windows Server 2016)

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9f4:a874:f039:8af6%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.168
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

**VM2** (blank - no operating system)

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : UPCE.CZ
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4f4:a874:1f7c:6c9%3
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.20
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.168
```

I can ping from VM1 (server) to VM2.

**I can not ping from VM2 to VM1 (server).**

Both VM1 and VM2 adapters are set in VMware to **Host-Only**: private network shared with the host.

Since SCCM 2012 deployment fails I started to troubleshoot by IP.

Thanks for helping me to get more education.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue could be Windows Firewall running on VM1 that would block pings. Turning off Windows Firewall or adding rule to allow ICMP traffic will fix it.